# how to split a sentence into words in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a column called address.I have to separate address which is not starting with capital letter that i can do with a single query like this

```
SELECT address FROM t1 
WHERE address NOT REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]';
```

but i want some thing like this 
if any word in the address is not starting with a capital  letter i have to put those address into a out file.

for example i have address like this

```
Bangalore vasantnagar
Hyderabad kukatpalli andhra pradesh india
mumbai Maharastra
Bangalore Cunningham Road Karnataka India
```

in the above example i have to take first 3 address and i have to save in a out file.

Hope u understand 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title seems entirely misleading to me!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
SELECT address FROM t1 
WHERE address NOT REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]'
INTO OUTFILE  'C:\\data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY  '\n'
```

for more info:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html